# Swift - Function as Variable with Self Reference

Tags: ios, swift

I've made a struct to hold data for my `UITableViewCell`s  that looks like so:

```
struct CellData {
    var title: String
    var action: () -> Void
    init(title: String, action: () -> Void) {
        self.title = title
        self.action = action
    }
}
```

And in my `TableViewController`, I'm setting it up like this:

```
lazy var buttonCells: [CellData] = [
    CellData(
        title: "Button 1",
        action: {
            **self.doSomething()**
        }
    ),
    CellData(
        title: "Button 2",
        action: {
            **self.doSomethingElse()**
        }
    )
]
```

However, the use of `self` inside the action causes it so that the `TableViewController` isn't `deinitialized` when the controller is dismissed (the `deinit` function isn't called). When I remove the `self` references, and replace it with something else, the `TableViewController` is `deinitialized` just fine. How can I go about fixing this abandoned memory issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your action definitions to use a capture group:

```
action: {
  [weak self] in

  guard let strongSelf = self else {
    return
  }
  strongSelf.doSomething()
}
```

What the `[weak self]` capture group declaration does is to convert self to a weak variable inside the block. If the owning object gets deallocated while the block is waiting to be called it gets passed nil instead.

Then once inside the block the guard statement tries to map the weak self definition to a strong local variable. If self is nil, it exits. If not, strongSelf contains an unwrapped strong reference to self and you proceed as normal.

Comment: Shouldn't I label it as weakSelf since technically it is a weakSelf reference that isn't nil? Or am I not understanding something correctly? @Duncan

Comment: weakSelf instead of strongSelf is what I'm referring to

Comment: You're not understanding something correctly. The `[weak self]` makes `self` into a weak optional inside the closure. Then the guard statement attempts to unwrap the now-optional variable self into a strong, non-opional reference to self, and save it in `strongSelf`. If it succeeds then `strongSelf` is a valid, non-optional reference to self for the duration of the closure. If it fails, the guard statement causes the closure to stop executing.

Comment: You could also ditch the `guard` and just say `self?.doSomething()` – although if there are multiple uses of `self` in the closure, then you should indeed use a `guard`.

Comment: Yup, that's true. using `self?.doSomething()` only makes sense if there is one and only one reference to self in the closure, and even then, I lean towards the guard since it provides a strong reference to `self` if you go back and add more code later.

Comment: I understood everything then Hamish's comment got me confused. After `in`: Can't I do `self?.doSomething()` next line `self?.anotherThing`?

Comment: Sure, you can use self? everywhere you need to refer to self. However, I think it's cleaner to have a guard statement at the top of the closure that exits if self is nil, and creates a strong reference to self if not.

Answer (score 1):

### Strong Reference Cycle

Inside your table view controller you are probably creating `CellData` like this right?

```
CellData(title: "Hello") { 
    // here you are using self
}
```

Or maybe you are writing this

```
CellData(title: "Hello", action: {
    // here you are using self
})
```

In both case there's a problem because you are creating a **Strong Reference Cycle**.

### Solution

you can avoid that using this code

```
CellData(title: "Hello") { [unowned self] in
    // here you can use self
}
```

### Last thing

Just remove the init in your struct, Swift will provide it for you ;)

```
struct CellData {
    let title: String
    let action: () -> ()
}
```

Comment: Better to use `[weak self]` than `[unowned self]` in your capture group. If you make it an unowned reference then it won't get set to nil if the enclosing object is deallocated. This creates a zombie, and a future crash.

Comment: using `[weak self]` followed by a guard statement is the way to go. (Or you can explicitly unwrap the optional every time you reference it, but that gets tedious.)

Comment: Also recommend using `[weak self]` and for clarity it's good to separate code into separate function which you execute from the handler with optional self reference, like: `self?.doSomeAction()`.